# Kerberised NFSv4 share for Yum repo

Tags: yum, kerberos

I am trying to set up a yum server where the packages are stored on an Kerberised NFSv4 share.  How do I get the service username under which apache and reposync run (my-yum-service-accnt) to be able to read and write to the NFSv4 share, since it can't kinit, being a service account?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The service *needs* to obtain Kerberos tickets one way or other – if not a password, then using a keytab.

Create whatever account you want on the Kerberos KDC, extract its keys to a keytab file. (I guess you could use the default host keytab for this, but a separate one would be better for security.)

Use [k5start](http://www.eyrie.org/~eagle/software/kstart/) to obtain tickets using the keytab. (For testing, a one-shot `kinit -k -t` can be used, but k5start – or at least a cronjob – is needed to periodically refresh them.)

Finally set `KRB5CCNAME` in Apache's environment pointing to the new ticket cache. (That would be done by editing httpd.service or the equivalent init.d script.)

If the server has MIT Kerberos 1.11 or newer, this can be done in a simpler way using the [keytab initiation](http://k5wiki.kerberos.org/wiki/Projects/Keytab_initiation) feature, by putting the keytab at `/var/lib/krb5/user/<apacheuid>/client.keytab`. This makes k5start and KRB5CCNAME unnecessary.